# iPhone - How can I right align PSTextFieldSpecifier of settings bundle

Tags: iphone, application-settings, settings-bundle

I've settings bundle in my iPhone application. How can I right align the PSTextFieldSpecifier value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. If you open the property list (Root.plist) file as a source and paste the following for each entry you want right-aligned:

```
    <key>IASKTextAlignment</key>
    <string>IASKUITextAlignmentCenter</string>
```

Comment: Note: This will only work when using "[In-App Settings Kit](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit)", not if you're managing your own Settings.bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same desire. What I currently do is to put some space bars after my title. So I have to text fields in my settings, Account and Password:

```
Account  TheName
Password *****
```

now I would count the chars that I need to get the same length of both strings. In this case the `"Account"` label has one char less then the `"Password"` label. So I would put the remaining characters count twice and append them to the label. In this case the label would be `"Account   "` (2x " ")

following I will replace the " " with "_" so that you can see the difference

```
Account__ TheName
Password *****
```

It looks different sized in your XCode Settings Bundle but on the device or in Simulator it will be fine